# How To Disable Multiselect of Listbox (Jlist) in Java

Tags: java, listbox, jlist

How do I disable multiselect in listbox (Jlist) of java?

Code:

```
configId.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
defaultModel = new FTCSDefaultListModel();
defaultModel.addElement(cecfgVo.getConfigIdList());
configId = new FTCSList(defaultModel);
configId.setVisibleRowCount(10);
JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(
JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
pane.setViewportView(configId);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use :

`JList list = new JList();
 list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);`

More informations on docs.oracle.com : [jList : setSelectionMode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setSelectionMode%28int%29)

Answer (score -3):

Use `setEnabled(boolean enabled)` inherited by JLIst from JComponent to enable / disable it like this:

yourJlistObject.setEnabled(false);

From JComponent [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setEnabled%28boolean%29):

> public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) Sets whether or not this
>   component is enabled. A component that is enabled may respond to user
>   input, while a component that is not enabled cannot respond to user
>   input. Some components may alter their visual representation when they
>   are disabled in order to provide feedback to the user that they cannot
>   take input. Note: Disabling a component does not disable its children.
>   Note: Disabling a lightweight component does not prevent it from receiving MouseEvents.

Comment: Why is this the correct answer? This will disable the whole Jlist, not multiple selection.